# Exporting Large amounts of data to a Tab Delimited file

Tags: export, oracle-sqldeveloper, csv

When attempting to export my query to a tab delimited file more than half of my data does not appear within the Tab delimited file.

There are arond 2000000 records brought back but only 1048575 records are brought back?

Any tips on how I could extend the export volume?

Comment: That's a suspicious number *8-) Which version of SQL Developer are you using, and how are you exporting - right-click from the query results grid?

Comment: The version is 12.1. And the export i right lcik on the query results and export ---- txt

Comment: can it be some kind of limitation? check MSDN

Comment: That's your Oracle DB version. what is your SQL Developer client version? Also how are you checking the file - are you actually counting the lines in the file e.g with a text editor, or are you opening it in, say, Excel, and only seeing that many rows? (Which I think is a limitation of Excel, though I thought it errored with larger files).

Comment: PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production. I am downloading it to the text file and then clicking on the bottom record --highlight ---edit ---go to